# При склеивании CSS файлов => пути к картинкам - невалидные

Tags: css, вёрстка, gulp, frontend

Проблема в том, что пути в файлах CSS относительные. Соответственно когда я все стили кладу в один файл - GULP использует те пути, что были изначально и, соответственно, получаем не валидные пути к картинкам.

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь GULP плагин, который может решить этот вопрос или придется править все пути вручную?

Comment: Задайте для пути картинок одну переменную, и правьте ее один раз при необходимости